# specify ssl ca and key in app config c# mysql connection string

Tags: c#, mysql, ssl, entity-framework-6

How can I specify the sslca file to be used by entity framework mysql in the app.config connection string.

My connection string currently looks like this;

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Model" connectionString="server=localhost;user id=username;password=*****;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=database_name;CharSet=utf8;SslMode=VerifyCA;CertificateFile=client-bundle.pfx;CertificatePassword=******;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

I get a keyword not recognised error when i use SslCa=ca.pem in the connection string.

So how do I specify the ca file to be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mixing PEM and PFX files is not supported by Oracle's MySQL Connector/NET. Specifically, as per [bug 95526](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=95526), `SslCa` is treated as an alias of `CertificateFile` so you can't use both at the same time.

I would normally recommend switching to [MySqlConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/), which does support using `SslCa` and `CertificateFile` simultaneously, but it doesn't support EF6 (only EF Core).

Instead, you'll have to drop the `CertificateFile` option, convert your certificates to PEM format, and use `SslKey` and `SslCert` instead (along with `SslCa`). I think this will also prevent you from using the `CertificatePassword` option (as that's only for PFX files).

Comment: I tried using the pem certificate, I still get the same keyword not recognised error for SslCa.
`<connectionStrings>  
    <add name="Model" connectionString="server=localhost;user id=username;password=*******;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=database_name;CharSet=utf8;SslMode=VerifyCA;SslCa=ca.pem;SslKey=key.pem;SslCert=cert.pem" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>`

Comment: @W.Mayo Are you using MySql.Data 8.0.16 or later? The `SslCa` option was added in that release.